# Cannot sort the elements of arrays within a larger array in ascending order using np.sort

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, sorting

1. Since I am working with multiple functions, I will only show the code I am working with for the array. Firstly, these are data from trials run through a rank filter. Now the result after splitting the trials is this:

```
concatTrials[:] = [rank(i) for i in concatTrials]
concatTrials = np.split(concatTrials,num_trials)
```

2. After this I get

```
[array(['9', '11', '4', '10', '2'], dtype='<U3'), array(['8', '7', '2', '14', '6'], dtype='<U3'), array(['8', '3', '8', '6', '11'], dtype='<U3'), array(['6', '13', '10', '11', '4'], dtype='<U3'), array(['3', '2', '5', '6', '3'], dtype='<U3'), array(['12', '3', '12', '5', '13'], dtype='<U3'), array(['2', '11', '9', '3', '2'], dtype='<U3'), array(['2', '13', '5', '11', '11'], dtype='<U3'), array(['10', '5', '7', '9', '3'], dtype='<U3'), array(['14', '7', '2', '8', '6'], dtype='<U3')]
```

3. Then I do

```
concatTrials = np.sort(concatTrials)
```

4. This gives me

```
[['10' '11' '2' '4' '9']
 ['14' '2' '6' '7' '8']
 ['11' '3' '6' '8' '8']
 ['10' '11' '13' '4' '6']
 ['2' '3' '3' '5' '6']
 ['12' '12' '13' '3' '5']
 ['11' '2' '2' '3' '9']
 ['11' '11' '13' '2' '5']
 ['10' '3' '5' '7' '9']
 ['14' '2' '6' '7' '8']]
```

However, my goal is to have each internal arrays elements sorted in ascending order. If anyone could help shed some light, that would be highly appreciated. My current idea is running a for loop to iterate through each subarray, sorting each one, but I am not sure how to begin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the elements are `str`s. Make them `int` (or `float`) first:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array(concatTrials , dtype=int)
arr.sort()
arr
```

Output:

```
array([[ 2,  4,  9, 10, 11],
       [ 2,  6,  7,  8, 14],
       [ 3,  6,  8,  8, 11],
       [ 4,  6, 10, 11, 13],
       [ 2,  3,  3,  5,  6],
       [ 3,  5, 12, 12, 13],
       [ 2,  2,  3,  9, 11],
       [ 2,  5, 11, 11, 13],
       [ 3,  5,  7,  9, 10],
       [ 2,  6,  7,  8, 14]])
```